# Form_for nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a website which has two models: company and contacts. I have a page that shows company info and theres a link to add a contact. My routes is like:

```
    resources :companies do
       resources :contacts 
    end
```

My doubt is that how can I use the paths tô create a new contact inside this page and how should be my new and create methods inside contact controller

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a: `rake routes` you will see all the available routes for your application.

For creating new contact, you have this route:

```
 new_company_contact GET    /companies/:company_id/contacts/new(.:format)      contacts#new
```

which means you can use `new_company_contact_path` helper method which will take you to the corresponding view `app/views/new.html.erb`. And, in the `contacts_controller`'s `new` method, you will have something like this:

```
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
```

And, your `create` method will look like this:

```
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      flash[:info] = "Contact saved successfully"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Make sure that you have `contact_params` private method in your `contacts_controller`:

```
  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have only one problem... In my edit.html.erb file, when I use <% form_for(@company) do |f| %> it says that I don't have the path. How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error? Which path is missing it's saying? If possible, post another question with the details and I will take a look.

Comment: The error is this: undefined method `contacts_path'
When I use <%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>

Comment: Right, you don't have that path. Your path is: `company_contacts_path` as you nested the `contact` resource inside the `company` resource in your routes. Write: `rake routes` in your console and you will see all the available routes in your application.

Comment: Right, so how should be my instance variable inside Form_for?

Comment: It should look like this: `<%= form_for [@company, @contact] do |f| %>`
And, in your controller, you will have: `@company = Company.find params[:company_id]`
`@contact = Contact.new(:company=>@company)`